# VB.NET Speed up cycle function

Tags: vb.net, cycle

I have this function to write bytes in a bin file.

```
    Public Shared Function writeFS(path As String, count As Integer) As Integer
        Using writer As New BinaryWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write), Encoding.ASCII)
            Dim x As Integer
            Do Until x = count
                writer.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)
                writer.Write(CByte(&HFF))
                x += 1
            Loop
        End Using
        Return -1
    End Function
```

I have a textBox that is the `count` value. Count is the number of byte to write into the file.

The problem is when i want to write 1mb+  it take like 10+ seconds because of the cycle.

I need a better/faster way to write hex value `FF` at the end of file `'value'` times.

I'm sorry if i've not explained very well.

Comment: Why are you doing this `writer.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)`?

Comment: Are you appending to an existing file, or creating a new one? Note that after each `Write`, it's already at the end of the file.

Comment: I'm appending on a existing file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be better:

```
Public Shared Function writeFS(path As String, count As Integer) As Integer
    Using writer As New BinaryWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write), Encoding.ASCII)
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim b as Byte
        b = CByte(&HFF)
        writer.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)
        Do Until x = count
            writer.Write(b)
            x += 1
        Loop
    End Using
    Return -1
End Function
```

That way you're not calling CByte every time. And there is no need to move to the end of the stream after each write.

Comment: yes but before start writing i need to go at the end of file, or will overwrite existing data at the start of the file. I can do it only one time before writing?

Comment: @DjRikyx OK, put `writer.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)` before the loop. (Edited my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Some questions before:
Why is the function Shared? Why do you use FileSHARE.Write? WriteShare means that OTHER process can write to the file, while YOU write to it. And WHY do you write single bytes that are all the same? And why does the function return -1 every time? Might be better fitter with a SUB? And why not using a simple for loop instead while?

```
Public Sub writeFS(path As String, count As Integer)
    Using Stream As New FileStream("", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)
        Stream.Write(Enumerable.Repeat(Of Byte)(255, count).ToArray, 0, count)
    End Using
End Sub
```

OK, if you need to write 100MB, this doesnt fit, but than you can partition your writes.

Comment: It is shared Because is a part of external class. I use fileshare because other programs need to have full access to the same file. The function posted here is not complete. i wrote only the part that i was needing help. However your questions have nothing to do with the problem. But thank you for your method, it works.